# Javascript Modulo (%) behaving strange

Tags: javascript, modulo

I am trying to calculate (6.6 % 1.1). I expect this to be 0, but I get 1.0999999999999996. You can easily reproduce this in the javascript console. My guess its an interal rounding bug? How do you solve this issue?

Comment: To answer the real question: You should not use the modulo operator on non-integer numbers. The problem is that `6.6 / 1.1` is not `6.0` but `5.999999999999999`, which will then be rounded down to `5` instead of `6`, so the difference is `6.6 - 5.0 * 1.1 = 1.1` instead of `6.6 - 6.0 * 1.1 = 0`. Do you really need the modulo operator? Usually, it is better to avoid it for non-natural numbers (or at least integers).

Comment: Well, it's fine to use `%` on non-integers; it's got well-defined semantics. The problem is that most people would never guess what those semantics are without looking it up, and even then figuring out *why* they're like that is kind-of challenging.

Comment: Consider using https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `%` operator acts on non-integer values in a way that's not exactly obvious. In an expression

```
n % d
```

what JavaScript does is find the biggest integer (I'll call it `q` to mirror the spec) that's less than `n / d`. It then computes the product `d * q`, and the result is the difference `n - (d * q)`.

(I've ignored the sign issue for simplicity.)

The idea makes sense of you think about integer remainders: if `n` and `d` are integers, then the formulas above make perfect sense. Take `17 % 3`. Well `17 / 3` is `5.something`, so `q` is `5` and the remainder is `17 - (5 * 3)` or `2`.

In your case, that process is made a little confusing by the fact that, with standard IEEE 754 floating point, `6.6 / 1.1` is not `6`; due to precision with representing decimal floating point values with binary floating point, it's just a tiny bit *less* than `6`. Thus, when `q` is calculated, it comes out to `5` instead of `6`. The answer is thus `6 - (5 * 1.1)`, or `6 - 5.5`, which is (again, imprecision) just a tiny bit less than `1.1`.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript use IEEE double-precision to store floating point numbers, so 6.6 is 6.5999999 (I guess?). You can use

```
(66 % 11)/10
```

to avoid errors.

Answer (score 0):

As the others have noted, you're seeing rounding effects from IEEE-754 floating point numbers. This isn't unique to JavaScript:

```
$ python
>>> 6.6 % 1.1
1.0999999999999992
```

The way to deal with float problems is to use an arbitrary precision math library:

- [mathjs](http://mathjs.org/)
- [BigDecimal.js](https://github.com/dtrebbien/BigDecimal.js)
- [crunch.js](http://crunch.js.org/)
- [big.js](https://mikemcl.github.io/big.js/)

For example, with [big.js](https://mikemcl.github.io/big.js/):

```
x = new Big(6.6)
// Big {s: 1, e: 0, c: Array[2]}
y = new Big(1.1)
// Big {s: 1, e: 0, c: Array[2]}
x.mod(y).toString()
// "0"
```